# SQL how to take 10% off normal price and how to increase with 10 %

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm still new to SQL, i have 2 questions that i don't know how to do.

First one is: List title and normal purchase price for those books that cost less than $ 100 in purchase if it's 20% off the price!

Second one is: List title and price increase for all books if the price goes up by 10%!

**The tables**

```
BOOKTYPES ( book_type_id (PK), book_type )

CATEGORIES ( category_id (PK), category )

PUBLISHERS ( publisher_id (PK), publisher, speciality, country )

BOOKS ( book_id (PK), title, publisher_id (FK), published_year,
 purchase_price, category_id (FK),purchase_date, pages,
 book_type_id (FK) )

AUTHORS ( author_id (PK), first_name, last_name, pseudonym )

AUTHORSHIP ( author_id (PK), book_id (PK) )
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images...)

Comment: Visiting the restroom during examination?

Comment: actually no it's not an examination, i have a laboration to do for the next 2 weeks and i just added the picture so the person who wanted to help could see the tables

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Number 1 is just simple math. Even being new to sql, this isn't hard to figure out which is why you are receiving so much push back here: `SELECT title, purchase_price FROM books WHERE purchase_price *.80 < 100` Surely you can figure out number two. You don't even need a WHERE clause or a JOIN (which are both like week 1 of SQL101. Just math.

Comment: @JNevill So that wrote, does it take 20% off from all boks and show only the ones that will be under $100 after the 20% take off? But when i write that code in postgre it doesn't show the price after the 20%. How do i do if i want to see both normal price and the price after 20%?

Comment: If you put a field in the SELECT portion of the SQL it will show up in the result set. FROM is for the tables that are needed for that result set and their relationships. WHERE is for filtering. Stick `purchase_price * .80` in the SELECT to have it show up. To give it a name (alias) in the result set then do `purchase_price * .80 AS discounted_price` in the SELECT.

Comment: @JNevill i have another question, do you think you can help me?

Answer (score -1):

I created these example in the SQL Server, but you can adapt it to postgresql

```
declare @BOOKS      table ( book_id int , title varchar(200), publisher_id int , 
                            published_year int, purchase_price decimal(16,2) , category_id int,purchase_date date , pages int , book_type_id int )

insert into @BOOKS (book_id, title , purchase_price) values 
 (1, 'Miscarriages of Justice in Canada: Causes, Responses, Remedies', 96.32)
,(2,'Crime and Punishment in the Russian Revolution: Mob Justice and Police in Petrograd', 34.84) 
,(3,'Selective Enforcement and International Criminal Law: The International Criminal Court and Africa', 101.77) 
,(4,'Secret Intelligence: A Reader',236.43)
,(5,'Skinhead History, Identity, and Culture', 186.24)

SELECT title, purchase_price ,purchase_price  * 0.80 purchase_priceOff  from @BOOKS where purchase_price * 0.80 < 100.

SELECT title, purchase_price ,purchase_price  * 1.10 purchase_priceUp  from @BOOKS
```

[image]